# Python, Regex: Is it possible to have 2 ending anchors?

Tags: python, regex

I am using this regex:

```
(r'(?<=DESCR:).*?(?=")')
```

to retrieve data from logs formatted like this

```
 DESCR: "Cisco ASR1004 Chassis"
```

or

```
NAME: "CISCO2951/K9", DESCR: "CISCO2951/K9 chassis, Hw Serial#: FTX1619AK8E, Hw Revision: 1.1"
```

I would want a statement with this logic.

Find the string starting after **'DESCR:'** and before **','** **OR** **'''**

Comment: Perhaps `r'(?<=DESCR:).*?(?=[\',])'`? Although there is no need in lookarounds: use `r'DESCR:(.*?)[\',]'` and get Group 1 value.

Comment: Does that help or do you need anything else? Please post some sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me aswer the question in the title, mainly:

> Is it possible to have 2 ending anchors?

If by anchors, you understand some context that is just checked but not consumed, yes, you may use an alternation in the *lookahead*.

If you want to match `a` before `b` or `cd`, use `a(?=b|cd)`.

So, your regex can be changed to `r'(?<=DESCR:).*?(?=\'|,)'`, or better, alternation can be turned into a character class here: `r'(?<=DESCR:).*?(?=[\',])'`.

However, there is no point in the *lookaround*, since we can use *capturing groups* to get the submatch value:

```
r'DESCR:(.*?)[\'",]'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pB9dF5/3)

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/CuiOxz):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'DESCR:\s*"(.*?)[\',"]')
s = "NAME: \"CISCO2951/K9\", DESCR: \"CISCO2951/K9 chassis, Hw Serial#: FTX1619AK8E, Hw Revision: 1.1\"\nDESCR: \"Cisco ASR1004 Chassis\""
print(p.findall(s))
```

Comment: Thanks for expounding on your comment! This was really helpful.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please also consider upvoting the answer if it proved helpful.